# How can I keep accents in xml file after editing it?

Tags: xml, powershell, diacritics

I'm trying to modify one attritube value in a xml config file, but when I save it, accent is replaced : ô => Ã´

Here is my code

```
    $xmlDoc = [XML](Get-Content "C:\MesInterface.config")
    $xmlDoc.configuration.ContrôleFlan.lastId = "0"
    $xmlDoc.Save("C:\MesInterface.config")
```

And what is happening after save

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<ContrÃ´leFlan lastId="0"/></configuration>
```

Comment: Your PowerShell code surely is in a ps1 file. Check the encoding of that ps1 file is UTF-8.

Comment: @MundoPeter it was already UTF8 encoded, I've switched to AINSI and now my XML is correct. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The general advice is to save the `.ps1` file encoded as UTF-8 ***with BOM*** when international characters are involved.

Powershell v5.1 and earlier assume `.ps1` files *without* a BOM (byte-order mark) to be encoded in the [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) codepage. From the [doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/vscode/understanding-file-encoding?view=powershell-7):

> *PowerShell 5.1 and below default to Windows-1252 encoding when there's no BOM.
>
> *For* interoperability reasons, it's best to save scripts in a Unicode format with a BOM.*
>
> [ ***EDIT*** ] The official documentation quoted above appears to be wrong, as pointed out by @mklement0 in a comment (and [reported](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6442) to MS). PowerShell defaults to the system-wide default [ANSI codepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-pages), instead, often but not necessarily Windows-1252. [ *end EDIT* ]

The OP wrote in a comment:

> [*the .ps1 file*] was already UTF8 encoded, I've switched to ANSI and now my XML is correct

This worked *in this case* because the character `ô` happens to exist in the Windows-1252 (ANSI) codepage.

However, saving the `.ps1` file as ANSI will still cause it to fail for characters outside the Windows-1252 codepage. For example, the following will fail if copy/pasted to a `.ps1` file saved with ANSI encoding, but will work if saved as UTF-8 with BOM.

```
    $xmlDoc = [XML](Get-Content "C:\MesInterface.config")
    $xmlDoc.configuration.ContrôleFlan.lastId = "αß©∂€"
    $xmlDoc.Save("C:\MesInterface.config")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ultimately independent aspects to consider:

- If your script file itself contains (code-relevant) non-ASCII characters such as `ô`,  you must ensure that the PowerShell engine interprets them correctly.

  - **The safest bet is to save your `*.ps1` files using UTF-8 encoding *with a BOM*** (UTF-16 with a BOM is also an option, but wasteful for files that primarily contain ASCII-range characters): it ensures that both PowerShell editions (Windows PowerShell and PowerShell [Core] v6+) read the file correctly and that all Unicode characters can be represented.
- **Since your XML document has an XML declaration that specifies its encoding - `encoding="utf-8"` - you should *defer to .NET's XML API*** to recognize the encoding both when the document is read from a file and when it is written back to a file.

  - By using the `.Save()` method you're already deferring to the API on *writing* the document back to the file, but the use of `Get-Content` - which knows nothing about XML - for *reading* means that the file can get misinterpreted; specifically, in the absence of a UTF-8 BOM, Windows PowerShell will read the file as *ANSI-encoded* (but note that PowerShell [Core] v6+ now sensibly defaults to UTF-8).
  - Therefore, instead of `Get-Content`, use the `[xml]` type's [`.Load()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load) method to read the file, which respects the encoding specified in the XML declaration:

```
$file = 'C:\MesInterface.config'

$xmlDoc = New-Object xml

$xmlDoc.Load($file)

$xmlDoc.configuration.ContrôleFlan.lastId = "0"

$xmlDoc.Save($file)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the encoding in code for your XML you could do something like this:

```
$settings = New-Object System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings
$settings.Encoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode

$writer = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create("c:\test\mydata.xml", $settings);

$xmlDoc.Save($writer)

$writer.Close()
```